# Web Browser Screen Shot

Tags: version-9, windows, .netlink

I have Safari, Opera, Chrome, Firefox and IE installed how might a get a browser screen shot of a set of HTML code from inside Mathematica(for any of those browsers)?

[image]

(Image is optional)

The shortest/leanest/fastest approach(within reason) is ideal.  For example: Waiting for a website to serve a screen shot is to long.  The solution should be local.

```
 screenshot["<!doctype html><i>Italicized text</i>"]
 screenshot["http://example.com"]
```

Possible ideas: [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/), [HTMLunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) ,http://watin.org/, [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) (fairly certain Selenium will work with right install and code).

Comment: Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1504034) + JLink

Comment: Ok, very good.
Ok, very good.
Ok, very good.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Copying my answer from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7622217/211232) (**edit**, now updated) ...

If you are on Windows (with .NET), then you could use Mathematica's NETLink functionality in conjunction with the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) class to capture a screenshot of a web page:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
LoadNETType["System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat", AllowShortContext -> False]
LoadNETType["System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState", AllowShortContext -> False]

Options[dotNetBrowserScreenshot] = {Width -> 1024, Height -> Automatic};
dotNetBrowserScreenshot[uri_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  NETBlock @ Module[{browser, bitmap, tempFile, image, bounds}
  , browser = NETNew["System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser"]
  ; browser@Width = OptionValue[Width]
  ; browser@ScrollBarsEnabled = False
  ; browser@ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
  ; browser@Navigate[uri]
  ; tempFile = Close@OpenWrite[]
  ; While[browser@ReadyState =!= System`Windows`Forms`WebBrowserReadyState`Complete
    , Pause[0.05]
    ]
  ; bounds = browser@Document@Body@ClientRectangle
  ; browser@Height = OptionValue[Height] /. Automatic -> bounds@Height
  ; bitmap = NETNew["System.Drawing.Bitmap", browser@Width, browser@Height]
  ; browser@DrawToBitmap[bitmap, bounds]
  ; browser@Dispose[]
  ; bitmap@Save[tempFile, System`Drawing`Imaging`ImageFormat`Png]
  ; bitmap@Dispose[]
  ; image = Import[tempFile, "PNG"]
  ; DeleteFile[tempFile]
  ; image
  ]
```

Sample use:

[image: sample screenshot]

The complete web page can be captured by using `Height -> Automatic` (which is the default).  Note that the screenshot is being displayed at reduced magnification.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  Interestingly though despite being local `AbsoluteTiming` seems to be reporting around 1s run time.  Not terrible but seems like there might be room for improvement.  I might try caching the opening of the browser or something to speed it up.

Comment: @LiamWilliam You might also get a speed-up by extracting the bytes from the .NET bitmap and constructing the _Mathematica_ image directly in memory.  This would avoid writing the bitmap to disk and then importing it (`Import` can be slow).

Comment: Neat stuff, WReach, +1!

Comment: @LiamWilliam Yes, we have to add `browser@ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True`.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: In case anyone is interested the following code allows you to send HTML to a function that responds with the output.  I am posting this because there seems to be a rendering issue if you write to a file like `<!doctype html><body>text</body>` and then try to render http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ZXi2SsME

Answer (score 7):

There is now a built-in way to do this:

```
WebImage["http://stackoverflow.com"]
```

[image]

```
session = StartWebSession["Chrome"];
WebExecute[session, "OpenPage" -> "http://stackoverflow.com"];
WebExecute[session, "CapturePage"]
```

[image]

```
WebExecute[session, "SetWindowSize" -> {600, 400}]
WebExecute[session, "CapturePage"]
```

[image]

Comment: Strognly relevant: ["Capturing the entire webpage with WebExecute's "CapturePage""](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197872/280).