# Is it possible to embed HTML webpage in a Mathematica notebook?

Tags: output-formatting, web-access

I am trying to display a webpage as an iframe in Mathematica.

The only option I have found is with `EmbededHTML`, but I can't get it to work for me. Example:

```
EmbeddedHTML[
  "<img src=\"http://xahlee.info/comp/Mathematica_logo/Mathematica_8_logo.png\">"
]
```

Comment: `EmbeddedHTML` is a structure used for cloud documents. On the desktop there is no support for embedding a webpage as would be done in a browser. If you just want the image you linked you can download it with `Import`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Shortly - not in Mathematica

In desktop Mathematica there isn't any built-in way to display an embedded web page.

Wolfram Cloud notebooks support `EmbeddedHTML` and your example will work just fine as this is ultimately handled by the browser.

`EmbeddedHTML` will preserve the content as raw html instead of showing a string output in your deployed page or in a cloud notebook. Then the browser can take care about fetching `img's` `src`.

#### Workarounds in Mathematica

You can fetch it as `XML` and provide a custom typesetting.

Or you can try to use tools for e.g. web screen shots: [Web Browser Screen Shot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44099/5478)

In your case where the source is a .png file, just import it. If you don't want to store it you can use this: [How to place an image inside a notebook, with the minimum memory footprint?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6157/5478)\